# chartJS - creating a chart with timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, charts

I am using angular to create chart on html using chart.js library. 
I want to achieve a line chart which is a collection of different date in a year length. To do that I am extracting data from database, creating JSON and in HTML getting json data to create chart. I want to create 6 different graphs on one chart.

Chart looks like this at the moment:

[image]

As you can see all different data is in one place which should create a line from February to October.

Code:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("lineCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var windowsData = new Array();
    var windowsSeries = [];
    //var windowsLabel = ['Jan','Feb','March','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var windowsLabel = [];
    var url = 'url';
    var regex = /^[A-Z]?|^[a-z]?/;
    //regex mach is equal to: A-AIX, W-Windows, C-CISCO, R-RHEL's


    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var j = response.data[i].Not_fully_compliant;
            var k = response.data[i].Policy;
            var d = response.data[i].date;
            if(k.match(regex)=="W"){               
                windowsData.push([j]);
                windowsSeries.push(k);
                windowsLabel.push(d);
                console.log(windowsLabel);
                }
            }        
    });
    $scope.labels = windowsLabel;
    $scope.series = windowsSeries;
    $scope.data = windowsData;
    $scope.options = {
       scales:{
           xAxes:[{
               type:'time',
               time: {
                   unit: 'month',
                   displayFormats:{
                       'month': 'MMM YYYY'
                       }
                   }
               }]
           }
       }    
});
```

Research: 
I was trying to apply Scatter.js which is a library which deals with problems like mine, but I wasn't able to implement it with angular.
http://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/

How my JSON Looks like:

```
[{"Policy": "Windows compliance-windows-int-windows7.nessus", 
"date": "2016-02-01 00:00:00", "Not_fully_compliant": "19"}, 
{"Policy": "Windows compliance-windows-int-dc-2012.nessus", 
"date": "2016-02-01 00:00:00", "Not_fully_compliant": "40"}, 
{"Policy": "Windows compliance-windows-dmz-server-2012.nessus", 
"date": "2016-02-01 00:00:00", "Not_fully_compliant": "0"}, 
{"Policy": "Windows compliance-windows-int-server-2003.nessus", 
"date": "2016-02-01 00:00:00", "Not_fully_compliant": "0"},
{"Policy": "Windows compliance-windows-int-server-2008.nessus", 
"date": "2016-02-01 00:00:00", "Not_fully_compliant": "1"}, 
{"Policy": "Windows compliance-windows-int-server-2012.nessus", 
"date": "2016-02-01 00:00:00", "Not_fully_compliant": "1"}]
```

It is a JSON for one day of Feb. I am not going to post lines of JSON, it is just to give you idea of the situation.

I want to create 6 different graphs for each policy from JSON and see how it changes in period of time. How can I do this?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Please format your json with something like jsoneditoronline.org so people don't have to scroll etc

Comment: Done Ivan. Hope it is better now.

Comment: So what your question is?

Comment: how to manage that the line appear on the graph from Feb to Oct. Right now it only overwrite the data and show the dots instead of lines.

Comment: do you have any other `date` field values other than `2016-02-01 00:00:00`?

Comment: yes... This is only the 1 day of json from database. I can upload file with all data, but it's really big. I will add snippet with JSON for couple dates, so it will be easier to copy it.

Comment: Can you please try putting not strings but parsed dates in `windowsLabel.push(d);`

Comment: Still the same problem. The thing is that xAxis works fine and it shows the correct scope of time. Just values on yAxis are still assigned to the first date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126535/discussion-between-ivan-and-maltesse).

Comment: @Ivan I have no idea how to chat with you. sorry...

Comment: By clicking that link you should be able to join. What I was saying there is this: `Another suspicious thing is windowsData.push([j]); You thus create a lot of series of length=1. Is that expected?`

Comment: Had any solution yet ? Because I see something, beside the date being «`2016-02-01 00:00:00`» everywhere in your json.

Comment: Hi Louys, as I said, I just posted one day of the JSON object as I didn't want to spam the page. Normally it has different values for different days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you for the support, but I have found the solution finally. 
The problem was that I have tried to push the arrays each time when I had different variable, so it was overwriting the values on each date.

The solution is to create an array, one for each policy and then assign the values to this array. Timeline on the xAxis will be suitable for the date pushed to labels.

This is the correct part of the code:

```
var jsondata = [],jsondata1 = [],jsondata2 = [],jsondata3 = [],jsondata4 = [],jsondata5 = [],data = [];
var jsonLabel = [], series=[];
var url = 'url';
$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        var j = response.data[i].Not_fully_compliant;
        var k = response.data[i].Policy;
        var d = response.data[i].date;

        if(k == "policy"){
            jsondata.push(j);
        }else if(k == "policy1"){
            jsondata1.push(j);
        }else if(k == "policy2"){
            jsondata2.push(j);
        }else if(k == "policy3"){
            jsondata3.push(j);
        }else if(k == "policy4"){
            jsondata4.push(j);
        }else if(k == "policy5"){
            jsondata5.push(j);
        }
        jsonLabel.push(d);
        series.push(k);
    }
});

$scope.labels = jsonLabel;
$scope.series = series;
$scope.data = [
    jsondata,jsondata1,jsondata2,jsondata3,jsondata4,jsondata5
];
```

Chart:

[image]

All i need to do is change the colors now, because this ones looks similar.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You look like *"mis-formatting"* the data to provide to chartJS.

Check this [documentation page on how to format it](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-points) and refer to it through out this explanation.

You actually provide your data as an array:

```
windowsData.push([j]);
```

Which ends in an array like this:

```
[19,40,0,0,1,1]
```

**It is only** the y-axis values extracted from your json.
Those AREN'T associated with their respective x-axis coord.

You should do something like this :

```
// Define a temp array.
var chartData = [];
```

In your get function where you *dissect* the json...
**Right now**... Associate the x and y value by pairs...
   and push them as `objects` in the temp array.

```
{x:value,y:value}
```

.

```
$http.get(url).then(function (response){
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        var j = response.data[i].Not_fully_compliant;
        var k = response.data[i].Policy;
        var d = response.data[i].date;
        if(k.match(regex)=="W"){               
            chartData.push( "{x:" +d+ ", y:" +j+ "}" );
            windowsSeries.push(k);
            windowsLabel.push(d);
            console.log(windowsLabel);
        }
    }
});

// Then...
$scope.data = {datasets:[{data:chartData}]};
```

So the datasets `object` provided to chartJS, which contains a "sub-object" `data`...
Which has to be an array of objects...

**Do you get deepness of the expected info ?**
      ;)

This is because you could have more than one line in the graph!

So this last **real data array** (for one line) would be:
  *(Please... Try it when you've fixed your json creation issue...

     → Different dates!! )*

```
[{
    x: 2016-02-01 00:00:00,
    y: 19
}, {
    x: 2016-02-01 00:00:00,
    y: 40
}, {
    x: 2016-02-01 00:00:00,
    y: 0
},{
    x: 2016-02-01 00:00:00,
    y: 0
}, {
    x: 2016-02-01 00:00:00,
    y: 1
}, {
    x: 2016-02-01 00:00:00,
    y: 1
}]
```

*Disclamer: Didn't test it... But it is certainly close... If not working at first attempt.*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Didn't see it yesterday. I will check your solution anyway. I hope it will create the graph not the dots on it. Your solution looks better than mine. Thank you!

Comment: Okay! For the line color, it is defined by `borderColor` within `datasets`. So try `$scope.data = {datasets:[{data:chartData, borderColor: 'rgb(30, 212, 78)'} ]};` (light green) and here is a handful [color picker](http://www.colorpicker.com/).

Comment: Just to let you know, that the solution doesn't work. There are no errors, console.log prints really nice array. I don't know why it doesn't work. I will leave it for now..

Comment: You're supposed to have defined the `data = {datasets:[{x,y},{x,y}]}` and the `options = {scale:{axes:[{...}]}}`... But did you define the `type = 'line'`?

Comment: I did exactly the same thing which you have written here. That's why it's so annoying